# How to change the pivot point of a link in URDF joint?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built simple robotic arm, where the Link1 is joined to the base_link through a revolute joint. When i try to move the link1 it is revolving on its own center instead pivoting the bottom to base_link. Here, how to change the pivot point from the center of link1 to its bottom and fix it to the base_link.

My urdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="myfirst" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

<joint name="joint1" type="revolute">
 <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
<limit effort="1000.0" lower="-0.548" upper="0.548" velocity="0.5"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="arm2"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

<link name="arm2">
<origin xyz="0 0 -0.3" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

</robot>
```

Result initial pose:

[image: image description]

Result end pose:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300945/how-to-change-the-pivot-point-of-a-link-in-urdf-joint?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2018-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A `cylinder` has its origin in the centre of the shape (all primitive geometry actually). That is why you're seeing the rotation as it is.

If you want the cylinder to rotate at one of its ends, you'll have to translate it half its own length up.

Something like:

```
<origin xyz="0 0 0.3" rpy="0 0 0" />
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2018-08-19**:
Thank you so much that helped!